# Postgresql UPDATE on multiple columns in the same table

Tags: node.js, postgresql

Im trying to update multiple columns in the same table. Im using node-postgres Here is what my code looks like.

```
client.query('UPDATE mytable SET column1 = ($1), column2 = ($2) WHERE id = ($3)',[data.a,data.b,data.id]);
```

The code goes through with no errors however the columns don't get updated. The data (data.a,data.b,data.id) is defined properly.

Am I missing something vital?

Comment: Please try the same thing with literal values in the query. This should give you a hind.

Comment: do you commit? or at least end session?..

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to all who helped.

All through the data was defined properly it was not actually being transferred on POST. Specifically data.id so the node-pg would not give an error but would not go through either since the data.id is missing.

After putting data.id within my form group it was solved.